# How to get a particular text from a file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a file that has data as follows
`a==1 b==2 c==9 x==4 d==5` ...etc  each of them are in new line I need to get the c==9 from a file and c==9 could be anywhere in the file so getting the value from using line number is not possible. I am looking to use bash as possible solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does `grep "c==" file` or `awk '/c==/' file` do what you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What exactly do you want and what you have tried? Simplest way is to use `awk`:

```
~$ cat test
a==1
b==1
dskjfhjks
kjfhkhd
c==1
kjfds

~$ awk '/c==1/ { print }' test
c==1
```